# Using constants in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

In my projects I typically use a constants file with values like `GUTTER` and `PADDING`to keep spacing in my UI consistent throughout.

I've started getting into Interface Builder and would like a way of using constants to space my elements instead of hard coding values.

So I was wondering if there is a way to set config values for my project that IB could read, whether they're environment vars or in a property list or whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such way. However, there are some standard values built in (expressed by concepts such as the *margin* of a view and the standard spacing between views).

Comment: Kinda lame, but I guess it'll do.